# About the eigenvalues of $A = (B + I)(B-I)^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $B$ s.t. $spectrum(B)=(\lambda_i(B))_i$ does not contain $1$.

1. Prove that the eigenvalues of $A = (B + I)(B-I)^{-1}$ are $\left\{\lambda_i(A) = \frac{\lambda_i(B) + 1}{\lambda_i(B) - 1};i\le n\right\}$.
2. Prove that, for every $i$, $Re(\lambda_i(A))<0$ if and only if the spectral radius of $B$ satisfies $\rho(B) < 1$.

Thank you so much in advance, especially if you can correct my statement.

Comment: Presumably $\rho(\cdot)$ denotes spectral radius?

Comment: yes, that is correct. I have added that.

Comment: Unless I'm not seeing something, the statement cannot be right.  If $B-I$ is invertible, and $v$ is an eigenvector of $v$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $v$ is still an eigenvalue of $A$ with eigenvalue as in your formula.  Unless the notation you are using implies that the eigenvalues are real and can be ordered (so that you are dealing with hermetian operators and the statement isn't just about the spectrum but also about preserving the ordering)?

Comment: unfortunately, the question that I have in-hand does not provide additional information. :| . I am also wondering about the ordering of the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2):

If the spectral radius is less than $1$, the result is pretty immediate.

Let $(v, \lambda)$ be an eigenpair for $B$.  Then $(v, \lambda + 1)$ is an eigenpair for $B+I$ and $(v, \lambda-1)$ is an eigenpair for $B-I$.  If $\lambda \not= 1$ (which is guaranteed if $\rho(B) < 1$) then $(v, \frac{1}{\lambda - 1})$ is an eigenpair for $(B-I)^{-1}$, and putting it together, $(v, \frac{\lambda +1}{\lambda-1})$ is an eigenpair for $A$.

The other direction is absolutely not true.  We can just look at $1 \times 1$ matrices for a counterexample.  For instance, take $B = 3$.  Then $\rho(B)= 3$, and yet still $A = 2$ has eigenvalue $2 = \frac{3 + 1}{3 - 1}$.